# The operation couldn’t be completed. (AWSMobileClient.AWSMobileClientError error 20.)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm currently running into this error when implementing the AWSMobileClient signUp function. I haven't really altered the code sample from the AWS page describing how to implement it, other than changing the attributes to fit my user pool attribute requirements.

First in viewDidLoad, I initialize the mobile client like so:

```
AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().initialize { (userState, error) in
        if let userState = userState {
            print("UserState: \(userState.rawValue)")
        } else if let error = error {
            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

Then I have the function for signing up. This is what the code looks like (I encapsulate this in a function called signUpUser):

```
AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().signUp(username: userEmail,
                                    password: userPass,
                                    userAttributes: ["email":userEmail, "given_name":userFirstName, "family_name": userLastName, "custom:school":userSchool]) { (signUpResult, error) in
if let signUpResult = signUpResult {
    switch(signUpResult.signUpConfirmationState) {
    case .confirmed:
        print("User is signed up and confirmed.")
    case .unconfirmed:
        print("User is not confirmed and needs verification via \(signUpResult.codeDeliveryDetails!.deliveryMedium) sent at \(signUpResult.codeDeliveryDetails!.destination!)")
    case .unknown:
        print("Unexpected case")
    }
} else if let error = error {
    if let error = error as? AWSMobileClientError {
        switch(error) {
        case .usernameExists(let message):
            print(message)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

When I run the app on my iPhone, I call this function when the "Sign Up Button" is clicked. In the debug window, I get the following error:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (AWSMobileClient.AWSMobileClientError error 20.)
```

That's the only info that appears in the Xcode console. Does anyone know how to go about debugging or fixing this?

EDIT: I'm not sure what the issue was that caused this error. I started a fresh project, set up a new cognito pool and backend services, and ported over the code from this project, which resulted in everything working perfectly. The error may have been from incorrectly setting up the user pool, or perhaps not allowing unauthorized access to the sign up function (not sure if I had that set to "No").

Comment: What version of SDK are you using? Update to the latest one and try again. Reference: https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/1147

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Turns out I was on 2.8.2, so I updated to 2.8.3 (newest one). However I still run into the same problem with the signUp function going into the error == error block, resulting in the same AWSMobileClientError.

Comment: Hey @Campbell I ran into the same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you exhaust the rest of the switch case there, you will be able to see what exactly is the error coming back from the service.

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59521025/2464632