# Not able to sign in with AWSMobileClient iOS. Getting AWSMobileClientError error 13

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I'm using the `AWSMobileClient` on iOS for authentication and I'm not able to sign in. I'm calling the [signin method](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/authentication#signin) and all I'm getting is the following error:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (AWSMobileClient.AWSMobileClientError error 13.)
```

This error is useless to me and I can't find any decent documentation on what this error means. Has anyone seen this? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/1538#issuecomment-491905913

You can cast the error as AWSMobileClientError and switch on it to exhaust the list of errors.

Alternatively, I've moved over the internal `message` property over to my app like this:

https://github.com/lawmicha/iOS-User-Authentication-with-Email-Facebook-Google/blob/master/AmplifyUserAuthentication1/Internal/ErrorMapper.swift

```
extension AWSMobileClientError {
    var message: String {
    switch self {
    case .aliasExists(let message),
         .badRequest(let message),
```

and then I can access the `message` on error after casting it to AWSMobileClientError from `if let error = error as? AWSMobileClientError`

You should keep in mind that the alternative method exposes the message which is a developer facing message and not a end-user facing message. Ideally when you need to provide an end-user facing message, you would use first method and map the error case to a specific localized message.